How to use python to create ORC file compressed with ZLIB compression level 9?
I want to create an ORC file compressed with ZLIB compression level 9.
Thing is, when using pyarrow.orc, I can only choose between "Speed" and "Compression" mode,
and can't control the compression level
E.g.
orc.write_table(table, '{0}_zlib.orc'.format(file_without_ext),
                compression='ZLIB', compression_strategy='COMPRESSION')

Ideally I'm looking for a non existing compression_level parameter, any help would be appreciated.

If you want better compression, did you consider using LZ4 or ZSTD?

@Olivier it's a requirement for me to use ZLIB and not other compression types,

how about first saving the file as you showed in code,then using zlib.compress(file.read(), level=9) and saving the file back? i.e. compress with zlib library instead?

@redoc Because that's not how it works. It would destroy the file structure.

The Apache ORC library (which is used internally by other libraries for ORC support) doesn't allow to set the compression level freely (neither the C++ nor the Java implementation).
The C++ library supports only CompressionStrategy_SPEED and CompressionStrategy_COMPRESSION (source):
enum CompressionStrategy { CompressionStrategy_SPEED = 0, CompressionStrategy_COMPRESSION };

The Java library offers an additional FASTEST option (source):
enum SpeedModifier {
    /* speed/compression tradeoffs */
    FASTEST,
    FAST,
    DEFAULT
  }

There is an open request in the project about this: Support maximum compression ratio in setSpeed. It was created a year ago but the feature has not been implemented so far.
So, unless you patch the library yourself, there is no way to set a high compression level.

Got it... That's what I thought, was trying to avoid patching zlib defaults, thanks
